# Sequences in C in a time efficient manner

Tags: c, sequence

I am making a simulation that updates at every timestep. I nearly 'kill' the virtual organisms in my grid  (its a cellular automatum) at 20000 timesteps. I want to write off data at `killing_time - 10000` and `killing_time - 100` for every 200 times I kill. Now I can write a for loop and iterate from 1 to 200 like this

```
for(i=1; i<=200; i++)
{
  if(Time%(i*killing_time-10000)==0 || Time%(i*killing_time-100)==0)
  {
```

etcetera. But than I would have to loop from 1 to 200 every timestep and do this calculation. How do I do this in an intelligent manner? Bram

Comment: Sorry, my friend, I'm afraid you will have to share more code and explain better its parts if you hope to get an answer. I read your question 3 times and I didn't understand much. How is yor grid defined? You update.. what?

Comment: Not clear. Some ideas on how to clarify: Give more context? Give an example for total number of time steps? Explain how many times you want to write data? Give an example for data format? Explain why you think your current solution is not efficient, and what you don't like about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem, this could be something like this...

```
/**
  gcc -std=c99 -o prog_c prog_c.c \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion \
      -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wvla \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <stdio.h>

void
simulate(void)
{
  const int killing_period=20000;
  int killing_time=killing_period;
  int Time=1;
  for(int kill_event=1; kill_event<=200; ++kill_event)
  {
    for(; Time<killing_time; ++Time)
    {
      if(Time==(killing_time-10000) || Time==(killing_time-100))
      {
        printf("display at %d\n", Time);
      }
      // recompute the grid here
    }
    printf("kill at %d\n", Time);
    killing_time+=killing_period;
  }
  printf("DONE\n");
}

int
main(void)
{
  simulate();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey friend, the trick that I seem to have missed is to define a variable called killing_time which is equal to killing period, and than to add killing period to that each cycle. That is very ingenious! Thank you! You are very kind.